# How can I insert image to end of the string and insert more than one image in UITextView with swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I created an UITextView and I can add image with image picker into text view. But I have some problem about replacement image. I want add this image end of the text. And I want to add images more than one. (like: text + image + text...). How can I solve this problem ? Can anyone help me ?

```
let pickImage = UIImageView() // this is for imagepickercontroller 

lazy var writePost: UITextView = {
    let wpost = UITextView()

    let images = pickImage
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    attachment.image = images.image
    images.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 220)
    images.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    wpost.textStorage.insert(attString, at: wpost.selectedRange.location)
    wpost.addSubview(images)

    wpost.textAlignment = .center
    wpost.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    wpost.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 16)

    wpost.isEditable = true
    wpost.isScrollEnabled = true
    wpost.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    wpost.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    wpost.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

    wpost.delegate = self

    return wpost
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use `UITextView`'s `textContainer`'s `exclusionPaths` property. The `exclusionPaths` property lets you assign an array of `UIBezierPath`s to your `textContainer`. When `exclusionPaths` are set, none of the `UITextView`'s text will appear within these paths. You could then add a `UIImageView` as a subview of the `UITextView`'s super view placed above the `UITextView` that has a frame equal to said exclusion path.

The end result will be a `UITextView` with a `UIImageView` placed above it. None of the `UITextView`'s text will be blocked by the `UIImageView` as the `UITextView`'s `textContainer`'s `exclusionPaths` have instructed the text not to populate there.

[image]

Here is an example of some code I've done to do something similar, with variable names changed to match your code a bit:

```swift
let imageView: UIImageView!

func addImageView() {
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: textView.frame.maxX - 200, y: textView.frame.maxY - 150, width: 200, height: 150))
    textView.superView.addSubview(imageView)
}

func setExclusionPath(for imageView: UIImageView) {
    let imageViewPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: textView.frame.maxX - imageView.frame.width, y: textView.frame.maxY - imageView.frame.height, width: imageView.frame.width, height: imageView.frame.height))
    textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths.append(imageViewPath)
}

func someMethod() {
    addImageView()
    setExclusionPath(for: self.imageView)
}
```

**Resources:**
[exclusionPaths reference from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444569-exclusionpaths)

Comment: first of all this is sensible solution thank you for this. But when I try to add second image or third one; there are always overlapping to first one and I want to put images end of the text. How can I handle it can you help me ?

Comment: I've updated the code so that the image is added to the bottom right corner, as opposed to the top left. As far as adding second or third images, it all depends on how you want the images to be arranged. Still, each imageView that you add should have a unique frame so that the image views do not overlap each other. And as long as you call `setExclusionPath` for each imageView, the text should wrap around the images.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concernign. But error : 'nil' cannot be assigned to type '[UIBezierPath]' sorry but I am the novice with swift. Do you mind if I show my codes for your review ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to do a boolean `==` not assigning `=`. Try the code out now.

Comment: Yeap i solve with like this and give yellow warning : Comparing non-optional value of type '[UIBezierPath]' to 'nil' always returns false.   Also still adding bottom right corner I mean I want to like (Text something + (imageView) + text something else + (imageview) ... )

Comment: Yeah I updated the code above and removed the boolean. As far as adding imageViews with text following it, you simply need to create the new imageView with a frame that is in the middle of the `UITextView`'s frame. It is up to you to set the image view frames as you find appropriate.

Comment: Still right bottom corner and still new images overlapping above to others. You are perfect explained situations but I don't know how/where I made a mistake.